# Azure FunctionApps vs Azure App Services for Compute intensive work

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, hangfire

I have 2 questions first related to hosting, second related to sdk/library to use:

I need to write a kind of work allocation service scheduler to people, which will run say every 1 hour to run compute intensive logic in background and push the results in our database. The input may be number of days to create schedule for, number of people available, count of tasks to be done.  So primarily its  compute intensive.

Should i host it in App Service or in Azure Function (TimerTrigger)?   This scheduler run as total background job and never called from UI or any backend API.

If i go App service way i have choice of either Hangfire or WebJob. How should i decide which is good for me.

Certainly quick execution with lesser cost is my criteia to move ahead.

Comment: App Service /  Hangfire is built for for web applications. It's not built for "compute intensive logic". How compute intensive is this really? In my opinion, Azure functions would be a simpler implementation

Answer (score 3):

One consideration for Azure function is how long the processing will take. Azure functions have a maximum time limit that depends on hosting plan. When you create a function app in Azure, you must choose a hosting plan for your app. There are three hosting plans available for Azure Functions: Consumption plan, Premium plan, and Dedicated (App Service) plan. An overview of hosting plans and their timeout durations is here: [Azure Functions scale and hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Unlimited duration is in Premium plan or Dedicated plan (Unlimited execution duration - 60 minutes guaranteed).

Maximum duration for Consumption plan is 10 minutes.